# Function stops iterating over loaded json after the first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui, steam-web-api

I am trying to get every achievement someone has in Team Fortress 2 and I have got it to the point where it gets the achievements and **did** iterate over them but now does not. This is the function and where it is being ran

Data.py

```
def resolveAchievements(ac):
    _ac = json.loads(ac)
    for achievement in _ac["playerstats"]["achievements"]:
        print(achievement)
        return acName.append(achievement["name"]), acDesc.append(achievement["description"]), acUnlock.append(achievement["achieved"])
```

Main.py

```
for a in acName:
     addText(a)
```

And the addText function if its needed:

```
def addText(t):
        layout.append([
             psg.Text(
             text=t,
             font=('Arial Bold', 14),
             size=14,
             expand_x=True,
             justification='center'
             )
        ])
```

It is only printing the first achievement twice and is saying None [] after. Here is what is being printed to the terminal:

```
{'apiname': 'TF_PLAY_GAME_EVERYCLASS', 'achieved': 0, 'unlocktime': 0, 'name': 'Head of the Class', 'description': 'Play a complete round with every class.'}
{'apiname': 'TF_PLAY_GAME_EVERYCLASS', 'achieved': 0, 'unlocktime': 0, 'name': 'Head of the Class', 'description': 'Play a complete round with every class.'}
None []
```

I am not sure what is going on but any help is appreciated!

Comment: `return` returns *immediately*; it doesn't wait for the loop to complete. You need to accumulate multiple values in a list and return that list *after* the loop is done.

Comment: @chepner im not sure why I did not think about that but you are completely right and this helped me, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace `return` with `yield` to return them one at a time.  It depends on how you use the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statement is *in* the loop, so you immediately return from the function (terminating the loop) after the first iteration.

I suspect you simply want to append values to three separate lists, then returning the three lists *after* the loop is complete.

```
def resolveAchievements(ac):
    _ac = json.loads(ac)
    acName = []
    acDesc = []
    acUnlock = []

    for achievement in _ac["playerstats"]["achievements"]:
        acName.append(achievement["name"])
        acDesc.append(achievement["description"])
        acUnlock.append(achievement["achieved"])

    return acName, acDesc, acUnlock
```